# How to open from a marker/pin in MapView a new Activity/Layout?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-activity

How can I open from a Pin/Marker a new Activity in Android MapView?

Like this, and then I´d like to tap on a marker and it should open a new activity,
how can I do this?

MyCode:

```
 private GeoPoint getPoint(double lat, double lon) {
return(new GeoPoint((int)(lat*1000000.0),
                      (int)(lon*1000000.0)));
```

}

private class SitesOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay {
    private List items=new ArrayList();

```
public SitesOverlay(Drawable marker) {
  super(marker);

  boundCenterBottom(marker);

  items.add(new OverlayItem(getPoint(47.17612,
          8.499727),
                            "TCS", "TCS Camping Brüggli"));
  items.add(new OverlayItem(getPoint(47.57612,
          8.499727),
                            "",
                            ""));
  items.add(new OverlayItem(getPoint(00.765136435316755,
                                      00.97989511489868),
                            "",
          ""));
  items.add(new OverlayItem(getPoint(00.0686417491799,
                                      00.01572942733765),
                            "",
                    ""));

  populate();
}

@Override
protected OverlayItem createItem(int i) {
  return(items.get(i));
}




@Override
protected final boolean onTap(int i) {
         //Do you job here.
       startActivity(new Intent(MaptestActivity.this,SettingsActivity.class));
    return false;
```

Comment: what is the problem with this code ?? post your logcat here

Comment: @Override
    protected final boolean onTap(int i) {
             //Do you job here.
           startActivity(new Intent(MaptestActivity.this,SettingsActivity.class));
  return false; I just can do it for 1 pin/marker

Comment: @ Rajeshwaran.T:No not really, now I changed my code with more or less this:https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-mapviewballoons

Comment: But now if I tab a ballon, I want to open a DetailView, is this possible? And thanks @Rajeshwaran.T for helping

Comment: Detail view means ?  start new activity?

Comment: Hmm, when you press a Item in a ListView this should open.

Comment: I don´t know how to call this :S

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-mapviewballoons

In this link  we have one package  " mapviewballoons.example.simple "

In this " mapviewballoons.example.simple " package has one class " SimpleItemizedOverlay.java " some modification in this code.

package mapviewballoons.example.simple;

public class SimpleItemizedOverlay extends BalloonItemizedOverlay {

```
private ArrayList<OverlayItem> m_overlays = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
private Context c;

public SimpleItemizedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker, MapView mapView) {
    super(boundCenter(defaultMarker), mapView);
    c = mapView.getContext();
}

public void addOverlay(OverlayItem overlay) {
    m_overlays.add(overlay);
    populate();

}

@Override
protected OverlayItem createItem(int i) {
    return m_overlays.get(i);
}

@Override
public int size() {
    return m_overlays.size();
}

@Override
protected boolean onBalloonTap(int index, OverlayItem item) {
    Toast.makeText(c, "onBalloonTap for overlay index " + index,
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    c.startActivity(new Intent(c.getApplicationContext(), NewActivity.class));

    return false;
}
```

}

This is modification code ,

```
@Override
protected boolean onBalloonTap(int index, OverlayItem item) {
    Toast.makeText(c, "onBalloonTap for overlay index " + index,
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    c.startActivity(new Intent(c.getApplicationContext(), NewActivity.class));

    return false;
}


  Call different activities,


@Override
protected boolean onBalloonTap(int index, OverlayItem item) {
    Toast.makeText(c, "onBalloonTap for overlay index " + index,
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            if (index == 0)
            {
    c.startActivity(new Intent(c.getApplicationContext(), NewActivity.class));
             } else {
              c.startActivity(new Intent(c.getApplicationContext(), secondNewActivity.class));

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but how to open diffrent actvitys?

Comment: How many activities are open ? , I can guess, each balloon overlay tap open different activities?

Comment: I don´t really unterstand what you mean :S the problem is this: I have 2 pin/marker on the Map with two diffrent balloons. Now when I press Ballon of Marker/Pin 1 it should open Activity1 and when I press the Ballon of Marker/Pin 2 it should open Activity2. Is this possible?

Comment: yes it is possible, we Tap a balloon that time get index position .

Comment: And are you so gentle to say me how to do? Because I started with Android Development one week ago and I cant really find a solution about this Problem on Google

Comment: I´ve started a new question with new code, can you help me there?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11782102/mapview-balloons-to-a-detailview