# Open Activity from OverlayItem

Tags: android, overlay, android-mapview

How can I open an Activity from a OverlayItem:
Here is my code now:

```
@Override
protected boolean onBalloonTap(int index) {

    if (index == 0) {
        c.startActivity(new Intent (c.getApplicationContext(),
                QuoteDetail.class));
```

This code works well to open a new Activity but I want to add this code to the code above:

```
public void onClick(View view) {
                 Intent i = new Intent(Test.this, QuoteDetail.class);
                 i.putExtra("position", 1);
                 startActivity(i);
```

How can I do this. Sorry for that stupid question, I´m a beginner

Comment: What are you trying to add?  i.putExtra("position",1)?

Comment: Because the QuoteDetail.class is a DetailView with diffrent informations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private Context c;    
@Override
    protected boolean onBalloonTap(int index) {

        if (index == 0) { 
    Intent intent = new Intent(c, QuoteDetail.class);
                    intent.putExtra("position", 1);
                    c.startActivity(intent); 
                  }
        }
```

Comment: I had to change the mContext to c, but you didnt know that. 10000000 times thank, you are the best :)

Comment: I cant vote, I need 15 reputation :( But when I reach 15 I'm going to vote :)